# Reference Request - bond lengths in PCl2F3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, reference-request

While writing an answer here, I needed references for bond lengths of $\ce{PF3Cl2}$ and $\ce{PF4Cl}$. The latter was easily found in reference **(1)**, whereas I could not find exact references for bond lengths in the former molecule.

[image: Bond lengths in PF4Cl]

References **(2)** and **(3)** contain information about the Raman spectra and $\ce{F^{19}}$ NMR spectra, but do not contain information about bond lengths. Reference **(2)** has information about the bond lengths of $\ce{PCl3F2}$, $\ce{PF5}$ and $\ce{PCl5}$, but not for $\ce{PF3Cl2}$.

**A reference for exact bond lengths in $\ce{PF3Cl2}$**, similar to the bond lengths shown above, is appreciated.

**References:**

1. Leiding, J., Woon, D. E., & Dunning, T. H. (2013). "Bonding in $\ce{PF2Cl}$, $\ce{PF3Cl}$ and $\ce{PF4Cl}$: insight into isomerism and apicophilicity from ab initio calculations and the recoupled pair bonding model". Theoretical Chemistry Accounts, 133(2). doi:[10.1007/s00214-013-1428-7](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00214-013-1428-7)
2. Griffiths, J. E., Carter, R. P., & Holmes, R. R. (1995). "Molecular Structures of $\ce{PCl4F}$, $\ce{PCl3F2}$, $\ce{PCl2F3}$, and $\ce{PF5}$: Infrared and low-temperature Raman Vibrational Spectra". Phosphorus, Sulfur, and Silicon and the Related Elements, 98(1-4), 11–31. doi:[10.1080/10426509508036938](https://doi.org/10.1080/10426509508036938)
3. Holmes, R. R., Carter, R. P., & Peterson, G. E. (1964). "Molecular Structures of $\ce{PCl4F}$, $\ce{PCl3F2}$, and $\ce{PCl2F3}$: Pure Chlorine Nuclear Quadrupole Resonance and Low Temperature $\ce{F^{19}}$ Nuclear Magnetic Resonance Spectra". Inorganic Chemistry, 3(12), 1748–1754. doi:[10.1021/ic50022a021](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic50022a021)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complete your literature survey, include this publication cited at least 11 times so far: «Dichlorotrifluorophosphorane (PCl2F3): molecular structure by gas-phase electron diffraction and quadratic force field» by French *et al.* in *Inorg. Chem.* 1985, **24**, 2774–2777, [doi 10.1021/ic00212a014](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic00212a014).  Despite the paywall, ACS's «In lieu of an abstract, this is the article's first page.» informs you about some key properties you search, values including ($2\sigma$ estimated) e.s.d.

---

*How* did I find this publication?  Because the English Wikipedia has [an entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus_trifluorodichloride) about it (don't overlook the [Chinese](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%89%E6%B0%9F%E4%BA%8C%E6%B0%AF%E5%8C%96%E7%A3%B7) including complementary information).

*But how* to know if Wikipedia indexed such a compound?  Way better than trial-and-error is to address this question to the [Wikipedia Chemical Structure Explorer](https://www.cheminfo.org/wikipedia/) allowing to query there by structure or string, which may lead you to the corresponding article (in Wikipedia).  It is backed by a public database ([GitHub repository](https://github.com/cheminfo/wikipedia)) initiated by Ertl *et al.*

Source: Ertl, P.; Patiny, L.; Sander, T.; Rufener, C.; Zasso M *J. Cheminf.*, 2015, **7**, 10, [doi 10.1186/s13321-015-0061-y](https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13321-015-0061-y), (open access).

Comment: Great answer, time to bookmark the chemical structure expolorer page :)